# How to add text below "POMODONE" in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, widget

I'm trying to modify my Flutter layout to display another piece of text below the "POMODONE" text. Here's the visual representation of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Currently, my layout looks like this:

[image]

**Here's my relevant code:**

```
  class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffF24004),
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("Container clicked");
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LogIn()));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 202,
                      height: 196,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Color(0xffF2B749),
                      ),
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text("P O M O D O N E", style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 22,
                        color: Color(0xff313640),
                      ),),
    
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 75,
                          height: 112,
                          child: Icon(Icons.check_rounded,
                              size: 100,
                              color: Color(0xffF3F5F4),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ) 
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I've tried duplicating the POMODONE text container, but it's not working as expected. Can you help me adjust my layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple. Since you want one widget below another one, you can use a `Column()` with setting the `mainAxisAlignment` to `MainAxisAlignment.center`:

```dart
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          "P O M O D O N E",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 22,
            color: Color(0xff313640),
          ),
        ),
        Text('click me')
      ],
    )
```

You'll have to remove the `Center()` widget in place of the `Column()`.

Using your code, a complete runnable example:

```dart
import 'package:braintrinig/pages/log_in.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffF24004),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print("Container clicked");
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LogIn()));
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 202,
                  height: 196,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Color(0xffF2B749),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text("P O M O D O N E", style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 22,
                        color: Color(0xff313640),
                      ),),
                      Text('Click me')
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 75,
                      height: 112,
                      child: Icon(Icons.check_rounded,
                        size: 100,
                        color: Color(0xffF3F5F4),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ) // Add Another Icon Here
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

I suggest you take your time to read the official documentation on [Layouts in Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout).